Are there any Gurus who believe only Sanatan Dharma is true and rest are false?
It is mentioned in Mahabharata that only Sanatana Dharma is true but most Gurus hold all religions to be similar.Are there any Gurus who say only Sanatana Dharma is true?
Also are there any Gurus who are purely vedic gurus and not advaita dvaita etc(Other than Arya Samaj)
